# How to install module.ko module without kernel signature or kernel rebuild in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers

How can I install any module in Ubuntu 16.04 without signing or without editing any kernel configurations. Is it possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module verification failed signature and/or required key missing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/483283/module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either disable secure boot or sign the kernel module.

Personally, I disable secure boot in the bios.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot

Or to manually sign the kernel module see

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/module-signing.txt

> ```
>       ==============================          KERNEL MODULE SIGNING FACILITY
>       ==============================
> ```
>
> CONTENTS
>
> - Overview.
> - Configuring module signing.
> - Generating signing keys.
> - Public keys in the kernel.
> - Manually signing modules.
> - Signed modules and stripping.
> - Loading signed modules.
> - Non-valid signatures and unsigned modules.
> - Administering/protecting the private key.
>
> ## ======== OVERVIEW
>
> The kernel module signing facility cryptographically signs modules
>   during installation and then checks the signature upon loading the
>   module.  This allows increased kernel security by disallowing the
>   loading of unsigned modules or modules signed with an invalid key. 
>   Module signing increases security by making it harder to load a
>   malicious module into the kernel.  The module signature checking is
>   done by the kernel so that it is not necessary to have trusted
>   userspace bits.
>
> This facility uses X.509 ITU-T standard certificates to encode the
>   public keys involved.  The signatures are not themselves encoded in
>   any industrial standard type.  The facility currently only supports
>   the RSA public key encryption standard (though it is pluggable and
>   permits others to be used).  The possible hash algorithms that can be
>   used are SHA-1, SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512 (the algorithm
>   is selected by data in the signature).
>
> ## ========================== CONFIGURING MODULE SIGNING
>
> The module signing facility is enabled by going to the "Enable
>   Loadable Module Support" section of the kernel configuration and
>   turning on
>
> CONFIG_MODULE_SIG   "Module signature verification"
>
> This has a number of options available:
>
> (1) "Require modules to be validly signed" (CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE)
>
> ```
>  This specifies how the kernel should deal with a module that has a
>  signature for which the key is not known or a module that is unsigned.
>
>  If this is off (ie. "permissive"), then modules for which the key is not
>  available and modules that are unsigned are permitted, but the kernel will
>  be marked as being tainted, and the concerned modules will be marked as
>  tainted, shown with the character 'E'.
>
>  If this is on (ie. "restrictive"), only modules that have a valid
>  signature that can be verified by a public key in the kernel's possession
>  will be loaded.  All other modules will generate an error.
>
>  Irrespective of the setting here, if the module has a signature block that
>  cannot be parsed, it will be rejected out of hand.
> ```
>
> (2) "Automatically sign all modules" (CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL)
>
> ```
>  If this is on then modules will be automatically signed during the
>  modules_install phase of a build.  If this is off, then the modules must
>  be signed manually using:
> ```
>
> scripts/sign-file
>
> (3) "Which hash algorithm should modules be signed with?"
>
> ```
>  This presents a choice of which hash algorithm the installation phase will
>  sign the modules with:
> ```
>
> CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA1      "Sign modules with SHA-1"
>     CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA224    "Sign modules with SHA-224"
>     CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA256    "Sign modules with SHA-256"
>     CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA384    "Sign modules with SHA-384"
>     CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA512    "Sign modules with SHA-512"
>
> ```
>  The algorithm selected here will also be built into the kernel (rather
>  than being a module) so that modules signed with that algorithm can have
>  their signatures checked without causing a dependency loop.
> ```
>
> (4) "File name or PKCS#11 URI of module signing key"
>   (CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY)
>
> ```
>  Setting this option to something other than its default of
>  "certs/signing_key.pem" will disable the autogeneration of signing keys
>  and allow the kernel modules to be signed with a key of your choosing.
>  The string provided should identify a file containing both a private key
>  and its corresponding X.509 certificate in PEM form, or — on systems where
>  the OpenSSL ENGINE_pkcs11 is functional — a PKCS#11 URI as defined by
>  RFC7512. In the latter case, the PKCS#11 URI should reference both a
>  certificate and a private key.
>
>  If the PEM file containing the private key is encrypted, or if the
>  PKCS#11 token requries a PIN, this can be provided at build time by
>  means of the KBUILD_SIGN_PIN variable.
> ```
>
> (5) "Additional X.509 keys for default system keyring"
>   (CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS)
>
> ```
>  This option can be set to the filename of a PEM-encoded file containing
>  additional certificates which will be included in the system keyring by
>  default.
> ```
>
> Note that enabling module signing adds a dependency on the OpenSSL
>   devel packages to the kernel build processes for the tool that does
>   the signing.
>
> ## ======================= GENERATING SIGNING KEYS
>
> Cryptographic keypairs are required to generate and check signatures. 
>   A private key is used to generate a signature and the corresponding
>   public key is used to check it.  The private key is only needed during
>   the build, after which it can be deleted or stored securely.  The
>   public key gets built into the kernel so that it can be used to check
>   the signatures as the modules are loaded.
>
> Under normal conditions, when CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY is unchanged from
>   its default, the kernel build will automatically generate a new
>   keypair using openssl if one does not exist in the file:
>
> certs/signing_key.pem
>
> during the building of vmlinux (the public part of the key needs to be
>   built into vmlinux) using parameters in the:
>
> certs/x509.genkey
>
> file (which is also generated if it does not already exist).
>
> It is strongly recommended that you provide your own x509.genkey file.
>
> Most notably, in the x509.genkey file, the req_distinguished_name
>   section should be altered from the default:
>
> [ req_distinguished_name ]  #O = Unspecified company    CN = Build time
>   autogenerated kernel key  #emailAddress =
>   unspecified.user@unspecified.company
>
> The generated RSA key size can also be set with:
>
> [ req ]     default_bits = 4096
>
> It is also possible to manually generate the key private/public files
>   using the x509.genkey key generation configuration file in the root
>   node of the Linux kernel sources tree and the openssl command.  The
>   following is an example to generate the public/private key files:
>
> openssl req -new -nodes -utf8 -sha256 -days 36500 -batch -x509 \
>        -config x509.genkey -outform PEM -out kernel_key.pem \
>        -keyout kernel_key.pem
>
> The full pathname for the resulting kernel_key.pem file can then be
>   specified in the CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY option, and the certificate and
>   key therein will be used instead of an autogenerated keypair.
>
> ## ========================= PUBLIC KEYS IN THE KERNEL
>
> The kernel contains a ring of public keys that can be viewed by root. 
>   They're in a keyring called ".system_keyring" that can be seen by:
>
> [root@deneb ~]# cat /proc/keys  ...     223c7853 I------     1 perm
>   1f030000     0     0 keyring   .system_keyring: 1     302d2d52 I------
>   1 perm 1f010000     0     0 asymmetri Fedora kernel signing key:
>   d69a84e6bce3d216b979e9505b3e3ef9a7118079: X509.RSA a7118079 []    ...
>
> Beyond the public key generated specifically for module signing,
>   additional trusted certificates can be provided in a PEM-encoded file
>   referenced by the CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS configuration option.
>
> Further, the architecture code may take public keys from a hardware
>   store and add those in also (e.g. from the UEFI key database).
>
> Finally, it is possible to add additional public keys by doing:
>
> keyctl padd asymmetric "" [.system_keyring-ID] <[key-file]
>
> e.g.:
>
> keyctl padd asymmetric "" 0x223c7853
>
> Note, however, that the kernel will only permit keys to be added to
>   .system_keyring *if* the new key's X.509 wrapper is validly signed by
>   a key that is already resident in the .system_keyring at the time the
>   key was added.
>
> ## ========================= MANUALLY SIGNING MODULES
>
> To manually sign a module, use the scripts/sign-file tool available in
>   the Linux kernel source tree.  The script requires 4 arguments:
>
> 1. The hash algorithm (e.g., sha256)
> 2. The private key filename or PKCS#11 URI
> 3. The public key filename
> 4. The kernel module to be signed
>
> The following is an example to sign a kernel module:
>
> scripts/sign-file sha512 kernel-signkey.priv \      kernel-signkey.x509
>   module.ko
>
> The hash algorithm used does not have to match the one configured, but
>   if it doesn't, you should make sure that hash algorithm is either
>   built into the kernel or can be loaded without requiring itself.
>
> If the private key requires a passphrase or PIN, it can be provided in
>   the $KBUILD_SIGN_PIN environment variable.
>
> ## ============================ SIGNED MODULES AND STRIPPING
>
> A signed module has a digital signature simply appended at the end. 
>   The string "~Module signature appended~." at the end of the module's
>   file confirms that a signature is present but it does not confirm that
>   the signature is valid!
>
> Signed modules are BRITTLE as the signature is outside of the defined
>   ELF container.  Thus they MAY NOT be stripped once the signature is
>   computed and attached.  Note the entire module is the signed payload,
>   including any and all debug information present at the time of
>   signing.
>
> ## ====================== LOADING SIGNED MODULES
>
> Modules are loaded with insmod, modprobe, init_module() or
>   finit_module(), exactly as for unsigned modules as no processing is
>   done in userspace.  The signature checking is all done within the
>   kernel.
>
> ## ========================================= NON-VALID SIGNATURES AND UNSIGNED MODULES
>
> If CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE is enabled or module.sig_enforce=1 is
>   supplied on the kernel command line, the kernel will only load validly
>   signed modules for which it has a public key.   Otherwise, it will
>   also load modules that are unsigned.   Any module for which the kernel
>   has a key, but which proves to have a signature mismatch will not be
>   permitted to load.
>
> Any module that has an unparseable signature will be rejected.
>
> ## ========================================= ADMINISTERING/PROTECTING THE PRIVATE KEY
>
> Since the private key is used to sign modules, viruses and malware
>   could use the private key to sign modules and compromise the operating
>   system.  The private key must be either destroyed or moved to a secure
>   location and not kept in the root node of the kernel source tree.

Comment: I had disabled secure boot and mokutil --sb-state shows "SecureBoot disabled".  But when installing module it fails and dmesg shows "module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel"

Comment: Simply stating it is not working is not really helping. You need to read the documentation and tell us what you have done to configure the kernel, what kernel, etc. See https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Signed_kernel_module_support and http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-and-cloud-90/module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-tainting-kernel-4175533442/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/483283/module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing

Comment: Thanks, Solved problem by replacing deprecated pci_dma_supported in driver code for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @karthik - glad you got it sorted, you should post the answer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have secure boot disableed yet my rtlwifi module validation fails and my kernel won't load it, hence no wifi

Comment: @George - Start a new question, be sure to post any error messages you may have

Answer (score 2):

I had this same driver loading issue. I simply passed `module.sig_enforce=0` at my grub linux kernel command line.

Here are steps:

**Permanently Add a Kernel Boot Parameter**

- Log in to the system and start a terminal window (*Applications* → *Accessories* → *Terminal*).
- At the `$` prompt, enter the command:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Enter your password when prompted by `[sudo]`.

If the file `/etc/default/grub` appears to be empty or does not exist, see the instructions for earlier releases above.

- In the editor window, use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then edit that line, adding your parameter(s) to the text inside the double-quotes after the words `quiet splash`. I added `module.sig_enforce=0`. (Be sure to add a SPACE after `splash` before adding your new parameter.)
- Click the *Save* button
- Close the editor window.
- In the terminal window at the `$` prompt, enter:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart the system.

Try loading your module and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 supports pci_set_dma_mask instead of pci_dma_supported for building PCI drivers. Wrong API usage will print secure boot key mismatch error when loading driver.

Comment: So what are the individual steps I should take to fix this?

Comment: Check if any deprecated functions are used in your driver, clear all the warnings when building your driver.

Answer (score 0):

On kernel v5.4, you can disable flag `MODULE_SIG_FORCE` and then rebuild the kernel.