# could not insert 'wl':(broadcom 43142) Key was rejected by service in a clearlinux kernel (also in XanMod Kernel) in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel, broadcom, 20.04

i am successfully running custom kernel with clearlinux configuration in my ubuntu 20.04 after [How to replace ubuntu 20.04 kernel with clearlinux kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230903/how-to-replace-ubuntu-20-04-kernel-with-clearlinux-kernel/1232217?noredirect=1#comment2080016_1232217)

Now time comes to make my broadcom 43142 work.

```
android@inspi:~$ uname -a
    Linux inspi 5.6.11+ #1 SMP Sun May 10 14:38:27 +0545 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    android@inspi:~$ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
    Release:    20.04
    Codename:   focal
    android@inspi:~$ #git clone https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl.git
    android@inspi:~$ cd broadcom-wl/
    android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ make clean
    KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` clean
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.11+'
    CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
    /home/android/broadcom-wl/Makefile:85: Neither CFG80211 nor Wireless Extension is enabled in kernel
      CLEAN   /home/android/broadcom-wl/Module.symvers
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.11+'
    android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ make
    KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.11+'
    CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
    Using CFG80211 API
      AR      /home/android/broadcom-wl/built-in.a
      CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/shared/linux_osl.o
      CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
      CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
      CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o
      LD [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/wl.o
    CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
    Using CFG80211 API
      MODPOST 1 modules
      CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/wl.mod.o
      LD [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/wl.ko
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.11+'
    android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ sudo make install
    [sudo] password for android: 
    install -D -m 755 wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
    android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ ls wl*
    wl.ko  wl.mod  wl.mod.c  wl.mod.o  wl.o
    android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ modinfo wl
    filename:       /lib/modules/5.6.11+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/wl.ko
    license:        MIXED/Proprietary
    alias:          pci:v*d*sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
    depends:        cfg80211
    retpoline:      Y
    name:           wl
    vermagic:       5.6.11+ SMP mod_unload 
    parm:           passivemode:int
    parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
    parm:           oneonly:int
    parm:           piomode:int
    parm:           instance_base:int
    parm:           nompc:int
    parm:           intf_name:string
    android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ cd
    android@inspi:~$ sudo modprobe wl
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Key was rejected by service
        android@inspi:~$ 
    android@inspi:~$ sudo dmesg | grep module
    [    1.259249] loop: module loaded
    [    8.461685] wl: Loading of module with unavailable key is rejected
    [   10.124790] wl: Loading of module with unavailable key is rejected
    [   11.616351] wl: Loading of module with unavailable key is rejected
    [   11.766984] wl: Loading of module with unavailable key is rejected
```

i did them . but not working.

1. Disabled Secured boot in BIOS.
2. sudo mokutil --disable-validation

   android@inspi:~$ sudo mokutil --sb-state
   [sudo] password for android: 
   SecureBoot disabled
3. onging..........

**How to load unsigned module in ubuntu?**

I tried them
[How to install module.ko module without kernel signature or kernel rebuild in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773734/how-to-install-module-ko-module-without-kernel-signature-or-kernel-rebuild-in-ub)

```
android@inspi:~$ cd broadcom-wl/
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ ls
built-in.a  lib       modules.order   README.md  wl.ko   wl.mod.c  wl.o
dkms.conf   Makefile  Module.symvers  src        wl.mod  wl.mod.o
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ uname -a
Linux inspi 5.6.12-xanmod1 #0 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 10 12:47:31 -03 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ ls
built-in.a  lib       modules.order   README.md  wl.ko   wl.mod.c  wl.o
dkms.conf   Makefile  Module.symvers  src        wl.mod  wl.mod.o
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ make clean
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.12-xanmod1'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
/home/android/broadcom-wl/Makefile:85: Neither CFG80211 nor Wireless Extension is enabled in kernel
  CLEAN   /home/android/broadcom-wl/Module.symvers
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.12-xanmod1'
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ make
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.12-xanmod1'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  AR      /home/android/broadcom-wl/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o
  LD [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/wl.o
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/wl.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/android/broadcom-wl/wl.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.12-xanmod1'
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for android: 
install -D -m 755 wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.6.12-xanmod1
android@inspi:~/broadcom-wl$
```

Comment: Is this helping? https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: I suggest that you raise an issue at github: https://github.com/antoineco/broadcom-wl/issues