# Wi Fi Not working in ubuntu 16.04 HP Stream

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, hp

Hi I have just switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04

**Compiled Log From This [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/602680)** → [Log for wireless diagnostics](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23288922)

I am just learning the system and have gone to use firefox and my internet is not working and saying that there are no connections available.

I'm kind of new to all this so simplifying things to me would help, please please help me as I have set it as my default OS.

Laptop is an HP Stream Notebook 13

Comment: Do you have ethernet, tethered or other internet access?

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal/553619#553619

Comment: If you can establish an internet connection, then do: `sudo apt update` and then: `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` Reboot and enjoy.

Comment: @chili555 just encounterd a problem ive just found out that my laptop does not have a ethernet slot built in, any alternative ways?

Comment: @chili555 typed in sudo dpkg -i bcmw1.deb dpkg: error processing archive bcmw*1.deb (--install): cannot access archive: no such file or directory errors were encounterd while processing: bcmw*1.deb I do have the file on my desktop tho

Answer (score 0):

Without any internet access nor the install DVD or USB, I suggest that you download the .deb file for *bcmwl-kernel-source* here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bcmwl-kernel-source Be certain to download the 32- or 64-bit version as appropriate. Find out what you need from the terminal:

```
arch
```

If the command returns *x86_64*, then yours is a 64-bit system and you need the *amd64* version. Likewise, download *dkms*: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/dkms

Transfer the deb files on a USB drive or similar to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer. Next, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot.

Comment: typed in sudo dpkg -i bcmw1.deb 
dpkg: error processing archive bcmw*1.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: no such file or directory 
errors were encounterd while processing:
bcmw*1.deb

I do have the file on my desktop tho

Comment: The last letter in `bcmwl*.deb` is not `1`, it is `l`.

Comment: still cannot find my internet modem have done this process

Comment: DKMS install completed.
Modprobe: ERROR : could not insert 'wl': required key not available
update-initrams: deferring update (trigger activated)
processing triggers for initramfs -tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/483283/module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing